# libiPhone-lib.a is too big after Unity build to xcode(size is about 1.1G!)

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, u3d

My unity version is 5.3.2p4 personal.I create an empty project and build with IL2CPP to xcode,there is a big file named libiPhone-lib.a. Even my project is empty,this file also is 1.1G!  If I build with Mono2x and choose a stripping level, this file become 500M,but Mono2x don't include ARM64.
How can I keep the libiPhone-lib.a in a small size and make my build both include ARMv7 & ARM64?

Answer (score 0):

Since the universal binary contains both an ARMv7 and an ARM64 slice of code, it will likely be about twice as large as one slice alone. Note though that the size you see on disk is not the actual size of the application. The application size will be smaller. See this thread on the Unity forums for more details:

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-5-3-x-build-size-increase-faq.383533/